# Using alias name in where clause - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a Summary table (data_summary) and a Summary Details table (data_summary_dtl). I'm applying the following query in data_summary_dtl table to get the

> Number of records in detail table for each record in the summary
>   table,select data if count is greater than 2

```
select summary_gid,COUNT(summary_gid) as varCount 
from data_summary_dtl 
group by summary_gid;
```

I can list the summary_id along with the count using the following query,

Which gives fine result for me, now my question is that how can i obtain the result of records that having count greater than `2`.

i had tried the following but not get the result as expected:

```
select summary_gid,COUNT(summary_gid) as varCount
from data_summary_dtl
where varCount > 2 
group by summary_gid; 

select summary_gid,COUNT(summary_gid) as varCount 
from data_summary_dtl
where COUNT(summary_gid) > 2
group by summary_gid;
```

Is there any other possibility to get the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this query

```
select summary_gid,COUNT(summary_gid) as varCount 
from  data_summary_dtl 
group by summary_gid
having COUNT(summary_gid)> 2
```

`Having` restricts the select list after applying the `GROUP BY` and used after it in query syntax.
`WHERE` is used before `GROUP BY` and restricts the select list before grouping in `GROUP BY`, so your aggregate functions like `COUNT()` which depend on `GROUP BY` do not yield results

About your queries:

```
select summary_gid,COUNT(summary_gid) as varCount from  data_summary_dtl 
where varCount > 2 group by summary_gid;
```

here the error would be

> Invalid column name varCount

because you can not use an alias defined in the `SELECT` list in `WHERE` or `GROUP BY`, `ORDER` or `HAVING` condition.

In second query

```
select summary_gid,COUNT(summary_gid) as varCount from  data_summary_dtl 
where COUNT(summary_gid) > 2 group by summary_gid;
```

you will receive error about

> using aggregate function `COUNT` in `WHERE` clause

Please note that it is perfectly OK to use `WHERE` in `GROUP BY` syntax. Example if you wanted to see details about a `summary_gid` which are greater than 10 and less than 15 then you can use

```
select summary_gid,COUNT(summary_gid) as varCount from  data_summary_dtl 
where summary_gid > 10 AND  summary_gid > 20 group by summary_gid;
```

You can also use `WHERE` and `HAVING` both with `GROUP BY` like this

```
select summary_gid,COUNT(summary_gid) as varCount from  data_summary_dtl 
where summary_gid > 10 AND  summary_gid > 20 group by summary_gid 
having COUNT(summary_gid)>1 ;
```

Comment: @un-lucky Thank you! I hope you also understood the role of `where` clause in group by query is only for pre-filtering the table before grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Use `having` clause along with `group by`:

```
select summary_gid,COUNT(summary_gid) as varCount 
from  data_summary_dtl 
group by summary_gid
having COUNT(summary_gid) > 2
```

We cannot use `WHERE` with aggregate functions. That is when `HAVING` clause comes to help.

Comment: Invalid column name 'varCount'.